# Vim batch delete/replace XML tags, but not content

Tags: html, vim, replace, tags

I have a set of XMLs and want to remove or replace all of the tags

ie) `<name>John doe</name>` and i want to be left with just `John Doe` or `John Doe,`

Thanks for any help

Comment: Don't waste people's time: learn markdown.

Comment: Do you really mean "i.e." (just the tag you specify) or do you mean "e.g." (the tag you give is an example)?

Answer (score 1):

For the exact textual match of `<name>John doe</name>`, you can use the following `:substitute` command:

```
:%s#<name>\(John doe\)</name>#\1#g
```

This will *capture* the name inside the tag (assuming its contents can be different), and replace the entire match with just the first captured group (`\1`).

For more information, `:help :substitute` has all the details. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

This basic substitution works in Vim as well as `sed`. For an automated processing of multiple files, I'd prefer the latter.

#### A stern warning about parsing XML with regular expressions

Note that XML is a rather complex format with many equivalent representations. Regular expressions are not powerful enough to correctly process all possible variants. It's alright for a quick replacement, if you know that the source document is well-formed in a particular format, and with a following inspection of the results, but I wouldn't use this for automation and production. There are better tools (e.g. [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)) for this job. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for a thorough discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Create vim script file with the following lines. Let's call it `script.vim`

```
%s/john doe/John Doe/gie
wa
```

Then, execute the command `vim -c "source script.vim" file.xml`.